# How to create a webpage which pops up the WIndows Security dialog

Tags: python, windows, security, microsoft-edge

I am building a program which opens a webpage and then clicks a button on said webpage. This webpage is part of an internal company network. I am writing in Python and I've used selenium  to open the webpage in Edge (because this is what the company uses) but as soon as Edge opens the page the Windows Security dialog pops up asking for a username and password. I was planning to use Autoit to fill out the prompt. The problem is I cannot constantly test this in the live company environment so I am looking to set up a dummy page on my local machine for testing purposes. Is there a way to set up a dummy page to force it to pop up the Windows Security prompt when opened?

Comment: A screenshot of the dialog might be helpful

Comment: I suggest that you can refer to [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/windows-authentication-in-Asp-Net/) to make a website using Windows Authentication. Then you can use this website to test automation.

Comment: @Anders I'm not sure how to upload images but here is a link to the same type of popup. https://linustechtips.com/uploads/monthly_2016_02/56bfa854c4e56_DialogBox.png.da889fb5d9982739643aea898fb14d96.png